# How to send data to server using Volley?

Tags: android, android-volley

I want to send data to server in the following format using Volley. How can I do this?

> [
>               ['cid' => 1, 'pid' => 1, 'quantity' => 5, 'rid' => 1, 'eid' => 1, 'did' => 1, 'takenAt' => '2017-07-24 04:03:23'],
>               ['cid' => 1, 'pid' => 1, 'quantity' => 5, 'rid' => 2, 'eid' => 1, 'did' => 1, 'takenAt' => '2017-07-24 04:03:23'],
>               ['cid' => 1, 'pid' => 1, 'quantity' => 5, 'rid' => 3, 'eid' => 1, 'did' => 1, 'takenAt' => '2017-07-24 04:03:23']
>           ];

So far I have done this but it's raising an exception

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Constant.API_SUBMIT_ORDER, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.e("DATA", "RESPONSE===" + response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
               error.printStackTrace();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                String time2 = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a ").format(cal.getTime());
                Map<String, String> orders = new HashMap<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < myProductArrayList.size(); i++) {
                    orders.put("cid", "1");
                    orders.put("skuid", myProductArrayList.get(i).getProductId());
                    orders.put("qty", "50");
                    orders.put("rid", "1");
                    orders.put("eid", "mukulsingh");
                    orders.put("did", "1");
                    orders.put("takenAt", time2);
                }
                return orders;
            }
        };

        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                MY_SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use these classes

**VollyRequests**

```
    public class VollyRequests {

       public void MakeStrRequest(final String Tag, String url, final ArrayList<RequestModel> list, final ResponceLisnter responceLisnter, final String HeaderKey) {
        MyLog.ShowLog("Url", url);

        StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    responceLisnter.getResponce(response, Tag);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                if (error instanceof TimeoutError || error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                    responceLisnter.getResponceError(VollyError.TIMEOUT_ERROR, Tag);
                } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                    responceLisnter.getResponceError(VollyError.AUTH_ERROR, Tag);
                } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                    responceLisnter.getResponceError(VollyError.SERVER_ERROR, Tag);
                } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                    responceLisnter.getResponceError(VollyError.NETWORK_ERROR, Tag);
                }
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                if (list.size() > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                        //MyLog.ShowLog(list.get(i).getKey(), list.get(i).getValue());
                        params.put(list.get(i).getKey(), list.get(i).getValue());

                    }
                }
                return params;
            }

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put(WebKeys.Headerkey, HeaderKey);
                return params;
            }
        };
        AbcApplication.getInstance().getRequestQueue().add(sr);
        sr.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(50000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    }
}
```

**VollyError**

```
    public class VollyError {
    public static String TIMEOUT_ERROR = "Please try again.";
    public static String NETWORK_ERROR = "Please check your network and try again.";
    public static String SERVER_ERROR = "Please try again.";
    public static String AUTH_ERROR = "Please try again.";
}
```

**RequestModel**

```
    public class RequestModel {

    String Key;
    String Value;

    public ArrayList<JSONObject> getJsonObjects() {
        return jsonObjects;
    }

    public void setJsonObjects(ArrayList<JSONObject> jsonObjects) {
        this.jsonObjects = jsonObjects;
    }

    ArrayList<JSONObject> jsonObjects;

    public RequestModel(String key, String value) {
        this.Key = key;
        this.Value = value;
    }
    public RequestModel(String key, ArrayList<JSONObject> jsonObjects) {
        this.Key = key;
        this.jsonObjects = jsonObjects;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return Value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        Value = value;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return Key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        Key = key;
    }

}
```

**ResponceLisnter**

```
    public interface ResponceLisnter {

    void getResponce(String str, String Tag) throws JSONException;

    void getResponceError(String errorStr, String Tag);
}
```

**How to call volley class:**

```
public void callingrequest(){
  VollyRequests  vollyRequest =new VollyRequests(); 
 ArrayList<RequestModel> list = new ArrayList<>();
                list.add(new RequestModel(key, value));

vollyRequests.MakeStrRequest(Tag, WebUrl, list, responceLisnter, HeaderKey);
}
   private ResponceLisnter responceLisnter = new ResponceLisnter() {
    @Override
    public void getResponce(final String responce, String Tag) {
       // here is responce
    }

    @Override
    public void getResponceError(String errorStr, String Tag) {
    // here is error
    }
};
```

**Application Class**

```
    public class AbcApplication extends Application  {

    //Static value Holders.
    private static AbcApplication mInstance;
    public static Context context;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    public static int captureImgCount = 0;

    public static synchronized AbcApplication getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

     @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
mInstance = this;

        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);}
public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        return mRequestQueue;
    }
```